# uninitialized constant User::Permissions (NameError)

Tags: ruby

I am in the process of learning how to use Classes, Modules and Namespaces. I am doing some playground stuff by myself and created a user with some permissions.

#### User.rb

```
class User
  include Permissions
end

u = User.new.set_permissions
```

#### Permissions.rb

```
module Permissions
  def set_permissions
    p 'Settings permissions'
  end
end
```

I am currently getting this error when I run this `User.rb` file.

> uninitialized constant User::Permissions (NameError)

Why would this be happening? I tried `include` and `require` but saw the same error. They are two serpeate files within the same folder. There are no subfolders like `lib` or anything in this directory.

Comment: where is `permissions.rb` located? in what path? app/models?

Answer (score 0):

You need this at the top of `user.rb`:

```
require_relative 'permissions'
```

This will load the code from `permissions.rb` so that when you call `include Permissions`, the `Permissions` module has been defined.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in that specific case is,

```
require './permission'

class User
  include Permission

  def permit
    set_permission
  end
end
```

then you can easily call `permit` on newly created `User` instance.

```
User.new.permit
```

this will let you achieve load and run a module function.